# Settings for uploading large files (video/mp4)?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, lamp

Background: I'm planning on using the JW FLV Media Player for streaming some videos:
http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/

Question: What settings, both PHP globals and php.ini, would I need to change in order to handle the uploading of large video files?

Sub-question: Is there anyway, through maybe the .htaccess file, that I could have the settings only apply to a single domain? I host several of my websites on the same server, and let's say if I changed the execution timeout to a few minutes for videos I wouldn't someone else on one of my other sites to have to wait through that kind of timeout for a regular upload if an error should occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .htaccess this will let you upload a 20MB file, and increase time for the script to 200 seconds. Most shared hosting won't let you do this though, and will keep a global limit.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

Comment: I figured as such, just want to be sure there wasn't any other settings I could change/tune for better performance. I'm also being hosted on a Hybrid VPS from KnownHost so I have the resources and access. Thanks!